# bash multiprocess - get results and assign to array

Tags: bash, multiprocessing

I want to get results from child processes using multiprocessing,
and then I want to assign these results into array type of variable.

my codes are like this

```
for (( i=0; i<${#servers[@]}; i++ ));
    do
        output_strings[$i]=$(ls) &
        pids[${i}]=$!
    done

    for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
        wait $pid
    done

    echo ${#output_strings[@]}
```

However, results were not assigned into the array.

Actually, if I change the code output_strings[$i]=$(ls) & to echo $(ls) &, it works.

How can I assign these results?

Comment: How can you assign results that haven't been computed yet? There's nothing like Futures or Promises in bash.

Comment: @choroba Oh... is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: @choroba I want to get sshpass command results using multiprocessing to decrease the network time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't send the assignment to the background. Send the command itself to the background:

```
output_strings[$i]=$(ls &)
```